# sorl-thumbnail - resize only if image is bigger then given dimmension

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

How can I prevent sorl-thumbnail from scaling up images which are smaller than desired thumbnail?

When scaling using {% thumbnail %} tag, the image is *always* scaled to desired dimmensions, while I want it to scale only images which are bigger than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you using `ImageField` I believe you can check the width/height first.

```
{% if image.width > 100 %}
    {% thumbnail image 100x100 as thumb %}
        <img src="{{ thumb.url }}"/>
    {% endthumbnail %}
{% else %}
    <img src="{{ image.url }}"/>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This is correct. If you want to set the width/height as *maximums* and not simply the actual size the image should be, then you *must* omit the `crop` parameter. If there is any crop done, it will size it exactly to the specified dimensions (Even if it's `crop="noop"`. That tripped me up for awhile.)

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the sorl-thumbnail built-in `upscale` filter for that?

```
{% thumbnail image "1500x1500" upscale=False as thumb %}
```

Default value for `upscale` is True. Set it to False to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: Great solution! Not so easy to find in the docs if you don't know that it exists.